# Showing white in the header part

Tags: html, css

I am using a dynarch calendar widget. The problem is, its working nice in chrome while in Firefox its a complete messy structure, in the header part in Firefox showing a weird height space showing on the left side some hidden button vertically aligned on top of each other. I tried a lot to make it work but it all went in vain. Does someone have time to look into what's wrong with my CSS.

Attaching links for a better insight.

[image]

[image]

```
.calendar {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     border: 1px solid #A8AFC0;
     font-size: 11px;
     border-radius: 4px;
     color: #000;
     cursor: default;
     background: white;
     font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
     z-index: 999999; 
 }

.calendar table thead tr th,
.calendar table thead tr td {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: #222222;
 }

.calendar table {
     border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
     width:238px;
     height: 250px;
     font-size: 11px;
     color: #000;
     cursor: default;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     font-family: verdana;
 }


.calendar .nav {
    background: transparent url(menuarrow.gif) no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
.calendar table tr:nth-of-type(odd){
    background:#fff !important;
}
.calendar table tr:nth-of-type(even){
    background:#fff !important;
}
.calendar thead .title { /* This holds the current "month, year" */
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    background: beige;
    color: #000;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}


.calendar thead .headrow { /* Row <TR> containing navigation buttons */
     background: white !important;border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

.calendar thead .daynames { /* Row <TR> containing the day names */

 }
.calendar .button {
     background: beige;
     border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
     border-left:0;
     border-right:0;
     border-radius: 0;
     color: #333;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: inline;
     padding: 6px 6px 4px;
     font-size: 12px;
 }

.calendar .button:hover {
     background: #dadada;
     border:0;
 }

.calendar thead .name { /* Cells <TD> containing the day names */
     border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
     text-align: center;
     font-weight: normal;
     background: #FFFFFF;
     color: black;
     font-family: verdana, sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
 }
```

Comment: Could you please make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your whole code?

Comment: I have resolved the problem, it was in other css file where buttons had inline-block value. Thanks for putting effort on sorting it out..